# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 pygresql

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql, installation, egg, pygresql

I'm not able to install pygresql. When I run pip install, I get this:

`(postgresql) Matts-MacBook-Pro:~ mattspeck$ pip install pygresql
Collecting pygresql
  Using cached PyGreSQL-5.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: pg_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/0q/fzk2q0_94tn_z1vlf446_jdr0000gn/T/pip-build-qOeMG3/pygresql/setup.py", line 88, in <module>
        pg_version = pg_version()
      File "/private/var/folders/0q/fzk2q0_94tn_z1vlf446_jdr0000gn/T/pip-build-qOeMG3/pygresql/setup.py", line 82, in pg_version
        match = re.search(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', pg_config('version'))
      File "/private/var/folders/0q/fzk2q0_94tn_z1vlf446_jdr0000gn/T/pip-build-qOeMG3/pygresql/setup.py", line 74, in pg_config
        raise Exception("pg_config tool is not available.")
    Exception: pg_config tool is not available.`

```
----------------------------------------
```

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0q/fzk2q0_94tn_z1vlf446_jdr0000gn/T/pip-build-qOeMG3/pygresql/`

I'm running Anaconda Python 2.7.13 on my computer.

I've tried installing both within and outside of the virtualenv. Anyone know why this is happening / if there is a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command before installing pygresql. It worked.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```